# Comparing pointers that are not necessarily associated with the same array

Tags: c++

The `C Programming Language` book by `Brian W Kernighan & Dennis M. Ritchie`, 2e, states the following on Pages 102-103:

> … pointers may be compared under certain circumstances.  If p and q
> point to members of the same array, then relations like ==, !=, <, >=,
> etc., work properly.  But the behavior is undefined for arithmetic or
> comparisons with pointers that do not point to members of the same
> array. (There is one exception: the address of the first element past
> the end of an array can be used in pointer arithmetic).

Does this restriction apply to C++ as well?  We have some legacy code that compares pointers (especially `void*`) based on their absolute address values, without considering whether or not they belong to the same array, and I am worried whether we need to revisit that code.

Comment: According to cppreference it's [unspecified](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) whether pointers to elements in different arrays compare greater than, less than, or equal to each other, but at least it's not undefined behavior.

Comment: A practical take on it based on my experience with legacy code, even if it's not the kind of code we would write now it has been around for years. So even without unit tests it usually has run for years and most (critical) bugs usually have been solved. A good strategy might be just to consider this code like any other 3rd party code. E.g. compile with the original compiler (known behavior), make an sdk like component out of it (header file/static lib) and link to that from newer code. It is good to weigh all options including refactoring and then make choices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Well, unspecified not undefined, which is much safer.

Converting to `int_ptr` is a guaranteed round trip however.  Also `std::less<>{}( a, b )` is guaranteed to be well behaved and consistent with `<` when `<` is specified.

This unspecified behaviour permits three things.

- Originally, segmented memory; pointers could ignore the segment and compare faster.
- Now, it permits certain optimizations.  Like assuming compared pointers where derived in certain ways.  And if the assumption is violated, the compiler can return anything.
- Blocks this comparison in constant evaluated code.

However, most compilers do not aggressively blow up when you violate that rule.  So it isn't a super high priority fix.  At least one compiler actually implements less as a raw `<`.